# Is it possible to securely generate two identical outputs based on one input, i.e. hashing that cannot be brute-forced

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, distributed-system

If you have a distributed system that requires generation of a secure output based on a certain sensitive input, the safest way is to simply use some form of database key that has no relationship to the input it represents. This ensures that the key is completely useless outside of the system and therefore completely secure.

However, since you are working in a distributed system, creating this key requires a central location to generate every key in order to ensure sanity among every piece of the system.

If you would like to create the same output key if two distinct pieces of the system receive the same input, you can encrypt or hash the value. However, this makes the key much less secure- it is possible to brute-force the encrypted/hashed input. The key is *not* completely useless outside the system and therefore insecure.

Is there any possible solution to this problem that would result in an entirely secure key generated by two distinct pieces of the system that received the same input, without needing to make an expensive central location call?

Comment: Treat the hash as a public key and do Diffie-Hellman using it and a private key that is shared throughout the system?  Since this question is theoretical it's probably better asked on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There exists some existing technologies to solve this problem it seems. Different "Vaultless"/"Stateless" tokenization technologies claim to solve this issue, however the claims of PANs and tokens having zero relationship with each other seem dubious, and despite the claims the technology does not seem adequately vetted.  
See more: https://securosis.com/blog/token-vaults-and-token-storage-tradeoffs